# Joining data frames by a numeric column with precision

Tags: r, dplyr

I got a couple of data frames I need to join by some numeric column. However, on some previous step of the process, the precision of the columns got mixed up (they might have been truncated, for example, or a CSV was saved and rounded it).

Is there a way to tell the join to happen with some specific precision?

I can't simply round or truncate, because they might still go in different directions.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

A <- tibble(X = 1:6, Y = runif(6))

B <- tibble(Z = 7:12, Y = A$Y + rnorm(6)/100)

inner_join(A, B, by = 'Y') # This results in no merge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a nice package, `fuzzyjoin`.

```
> fuzzyjoin::difference_inner_join(A, B,max_dist = 0.03)
Joining by: "Y"
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      X    Y.x     Z    Y.y
  <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
1     1 0.288      7 0.288 
2     2 0.788      8 0.790 
3     3 0.409      9 0.426 
4     4 0.883     10 0.888 
5     5 0.940     11 0.928 
6     6 0.0456    12 0.0387
```